# Method for creating buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, subview

I have custom button class "EHCheckBox". There are many buttons in my app, so i try to optimize my code and create button in one line instead of 10. In my view, in **viewDidLoad** I call method witch call method which create my buttons.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  .....
  [self buttons];
  .....
}

-(void)buttons
{
    [self addNewBut:pcswitch Title:@"   Switch" Column:3 Position:5 Dropable:NO Hide:NO]
}
-(void)addNewBut:(EHCheckBox*)checkBoxName Title:(NSString*)checkBoxTitle Column:(int)checkBoxColumn Position:(int)checkBoxPosition Dropable:(BOOL)checkBoxDropable Hide:(BOOL)hide
{
    checkBoxName = [EHCheckBox buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [checkBoxName setTitle:NSLocalizedString(checkBoxTitle, @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    checkBoxName.hidden = hide;

    if (checkBoxDropable) {
        [checkBoxName setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckButton1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [checkBoxName setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckButtonSelect1.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }else{
        [checkBoxName setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [checkBoxName setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckButtonSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }

    int firstColX = 45;
    int firstColY = 125;
    int width = 140;
    int height = 36;
    int widhtTwo = 18;

    int x = firstColX + (checkBoxColumn - 1)*(width+widhtTwo);
    int y = firstColY + (checkBoxPosition - 1)*(height);

    checkBoxName.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 140, 50);
    [self.view addSubview:checkBoxName];
}
```

hide = YES because i have other methods which unhides and hides buttons, but they doesn't works because in view my button is **nil**, and i don't understand why? Maybe my method should return these button? Thank you.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the `addNewBut:...` method and take it from there.

Comment: @dandan78 "...in view my button is nil..." these, means that i used debug.

Comment: What about `pcswitch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot understand what's your goal and code here but I really suggest to use categories. In this case the could should look better and more organized.

So, for example, you can follow this approach.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIButton (Factory)

+ (UIButton*)buttonWithTitle:(NSString*)title column:(int)column position:(int)position dropable:(BOOL)dropable hide:(BOOL)hide;

@end
```

and

```
#import "UIButton+Factory.h"

@implementation UIButton (Factory)

+ (UIButton*)buttonWithTitle:(NSString*)title column:(int)column position:(int)position dropable:(BOOL)dropable hide:(BOOL)hide {

    UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(title, @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setHidden:hide];

    if (dropable) {
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckButton1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckButtonSelect1.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    } else {
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckButtonSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }

    int firstColX = 45;
    int firstColY = 125;
    int width = 140;
    int height = 36;
    int widhtTwo = 18;

    int x = firstColX + (column - 1)*(width+widhtTwo);
    int y = firstColY + (position - 1)*(height);
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 140, 50);

    return button;
}

@end
```

You can use this category like the following. You need to import `#import "UIButton+Factory.h"`.

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithTitle:@"test" column:1 position:1 dropable:YES hide:NO];
[viewWhereYouWantToAddTheButton addSubview:button];
```

A note. If you pass `0` to both column and position, your button will assume negative `x` and `y`. Hence, you won't see it.

Comment: your code inspired me, I wrote the constructor of class, all works, thank you very much!

Comment: i dont want to write all time addSubView... so i modernize these method, but i have some prombles vith selector, it's unrecognized all the time, as i understand it try to call in not in my view, my method
initWithTitle:(NSString*)checkBoxTitle Column:(int)checkBoxColumn Position:(int)checkBoxPosition Dropable:(BOOL)checkBoxDropable Hide:(BOOL)hide selector:(SEL)action viewController:(UIView*)view

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what you mean? I cannot understand...@RomanSimenok